# What would be the equivalent of customers.get in V11 Google Ads API?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have an old API that I need to support. It uses the v9 of Google Ads API:

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v9/customers/get

Now I need to update to V11 but can't find an equivalent endpoint because it was removed.

Anyone? :(

Answer (score 0):

According to this [release note](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/release-notes#v10), since v10 upto the latest API version (v11), the get method and any services that exclusively had a get method have been removed. Retrieve objects with Search and SearchStream from GoogleAdsService. With this, the report type that I can suggest to get the account level information is the [customer](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v11/customer) report.